# Show xml in current/new window

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, asp.net-mvc-3, formatting

I have a view displaying data from a model. My model contains a string property which is actually some xml. I would like to display this xml in my view in a simple div (or in a new page) but it's important to have it nicely formatted so it's easily readable to the user.

What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: All the answers helped. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@model MyViewModel
...
<pre>@XElement.Parse(Model.SomeStringPropertyContainingXml)</pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can fromat it using [`XElement.Parse(yourString)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.parse.aspx):

```
string niclyformattedXml = XElement.Parse(unformattedString).ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the XML string is already nicely formatted with tabs you can render it in a `<pre></pre>` tag.

You can simply output the string in there using `<%: Model.XmlValue %>` or `@Model.XmlValue` (to ensure angle-brackets etc are HTML-encoded).

Use a bit of CSS then to control text size etc.

If it's not already formatted then you could load it into an `XElement` and then call the [`ToString(SaveOptions)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb551415.aspx) method - which in default mode will use indenting.